# Output error if cd tries to switch to non existing directory - own shell

Tags: c, cd

So me and my partner have to create our own shell in which cd is supposed to change the directory. We have written and use this code to change directory if possible, but we can't quite figure out as to how we get the part done where it'd put out an error in case there directory does not exist.

```
    //check if cd was typed
if(strcmp(parsed_command->argv[0], "cd") == 0){
    //if more than one argument -> error
    if(parsed_command->argv[2]){
        printf("Too many arguments!");
        free(parsed_command);
        return;
    }
    //read directory
    char* dir = parsed_command->argv[1];
    //execute change and check if error
    if(chdir(dir) == -1){
        perror("cd:");
    }
    //free memory
    free(parsed_command);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Why your `perror` call isn't enough?

Comment: According to our professor the code fails to put out the error in the way it's supposed to. We also wrote it thinking it would suffice but they don't think so.
Hence why I asked for an alternative.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the expected output vs. the actual output.

Answer (score 0):

You're already printing an error by using `perror()`. I don't quite get what you specifically want.
What you can do is printing additional info, for example the directory that doesn't exist.
You could to this by using `fprintf` instead of perror and adding your own infos:

```
fprintf(stderr, "The dir: %s does not exist.", dir);
```

Note that `fprintf` uses the stderr as output channel here.